# Aerospike Write Fails with server error 1

Tags: aerospike

Case :
Writes for some  keys are failing. And they fail even on retry with the following error in in server log :

> Aug 30 2016 07:14:58 GMT: WARNING (drv_ssd): (drv_ssd.c:1225) read:
>   bad block magic offset 1704448 Aug 30 2016 07:14:58 GMT: WARNING
>   (drv_ssd): (drv_ssd.c:1283) get_key: failed
>   as_storage_record_read_ssd() Aug 30 2016 07:14:58 GMT: WARNING (rw):
>   (thr_rw.c:3440) {userdata} write_local: can't get stored key
>   :0x0ac772018687b572e1a9be79ad0c168dccbee955

Following is the config file on all 3 nodes :

```
service {
  user root
  group root
  paxos-single-replica-limit 1 # Number of nodes where the replica count is automatically reduced to 1.
  pidfile /var/run/aerospike/asd.pid

  ## SET TO NUMBER OF CORES ##
  service-threads 8
  transaction-queues 8
  scan-threads 8
  ###########################

  ## DONT CHANGE ##
  transaction-threads-per-queue 3
  proto-fd-idle-ms 600000
  proto-fd-max 100000
  batch-max-requests 10000
  migrate-threads 2
  replication-fire-and-forget true
  ##########################
}

logging {
  file /var/log/aerospike/aerospike.log {
    context any info
  }
}

network {
  service {
    address any
    port 3000
  }

  heartbeat {
    mode mesh
    port 3002

    mesh-seed-address-port 10.0.23.46 3002
    mesh-seed-address-port 10.0.23.7 3002
    mesh-seed-address-port 10.0.23.52 3002

    interval 150
    timeout 20
  }

  fabric {
    port 3001
  }

  info {
    port 3003
  }
}

namespace userdata {
  replication-factor 2
  #### CHANGE FOR INSTANCE ###
  memory-size 30G
  ############################
  default-ttl 0 # 30 days, use 0 to never expire/evict.
  storage-engine device {
    ## COLD START AND NO SHADOW DEVICE ##
    cold-start-empty true
    device /dev/xvdf
    #####################################
    ### 1MB FOR INSTANCE STORE ###
    write-block-size 1024K
    #############################
  }
# storage-engine memory
}

namespace user_config_data {
        replication-factor 2
        memory-size 5G
        default-ttl 0
        storage-engine device {
                cold-start-empty true
                device /dev/xvdf
                write-block-size 1024K
        }
}
```

Currently we don't have any data in the namespace `user_config_data`

**Note: Few days back aerospike was restarted on all 3 nodes simultaneously by mistake causing all data to be lost.**

Answer (score 3):

You are using the same device for both namespaces. That is wrong. This has too many elements of wrong configuration and what went wrong. I would highly recommend taking this up at aerospike forums at http://discuss.aerospike.com/

Comment: Yes got it that two namespaces shouldn't be on same raw device.

Answer (score 2):

> Few days back aerospike was restarted on all 3 nodes simultaneously by mistake causing all data to be lost.

You could have recovered the data by shutting down the nodes again and removing the cold-start-empty parameter then restart them. Afterwards you would set cold-start-empty again and handle returned deletes.